# Get the path of a image (ActiveX Control)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble to get a file path in Excel VBA.

I created a module to get the file path and load it on an image (ActiveX Control)

```
img_1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="File Type (*.jpg), *.jpg")
Sheet8.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(mg_1)
```

However, it's just a function, when I call the main function the value of the variable (img_1) is deleted.
I would like to get the file path trough the "Sheet8.Image1.Picture".

How could I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of the variable (img_1) is deleted."?

Comment: it's no saved because cause it's a local variable

Comment: But what do you mean by saving? Is the chosen picture applied on the `Image1` control? If so, what else do you need? Do you want saving the picture path somewhere in a workbook cell? If so, use activeSheet.range("A1").Value = img_1`. If not, please clearly explain what you want.